# Show an Alert if the user write a determinate word in a window. (keyCodes event)

Tags: javascript, html

Is that possible with js keyCodes event to show an alert if the user write a determinate word?
For example: the user is in homepage, write (without input) "Hello" and appear an alert like "Congratulation, you found the secret word!".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind event listener and keep track of what was typed. Basic idea

```js
const codes = {
  hello: () => console.log('hello there'),
  'funky chicken': () => window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ',
}

function hotKeyListener () {
  let str = '';
  let timeout;
  const msDelay = 400;
  
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    if (timeout) window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    str += evt.key;
    const action = codes[str];
    if (action) {
      str = '';
      action();
    } else {
      timeout = window.setTimeout(() => str = '', msDelay);
    }
  });
}

hotKeyListener();
```